# Import cv2 illegal values, failing to import

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python 3.9.0 with pip version 20.3.1

I have successfully installed numpy-1.19.4 opencv-python-4.4.0.46 using `pip install opencv-python`

However, when I run `import cv2` i get a myriad of errors

```
C:\Users\User11>python
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\User11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\User11\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https://tinyurl.co....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I've reinstalled python / nympy & openCV

I've tried `pip install -U numpy` in order to fix `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing previous version of numpy, 1.19.3 should fix this. `python -m pip install numpy==1.19.3`